# R - Calculating the mean of a DataFrame using a list

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime, mean

I am trying to calculate the average measurements across 10 minute periods of time. I used this code to create a time range:

```
LDT_Range
[1] "2018-06-02 08:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 08:50:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 09:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 09:10:00 EDT"
 [5] "2018-06-02 09:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 09:30:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 09:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 09:50:00 EDT"
 [9] "2018-06-02 10:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 10:10:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 10:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 10:30:00 EDT"
[13] "2018-06-02 10:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 10:50:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 11:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 11:10:00 EDT"
[17] "2018-06-02 11:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 11:30:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 11:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 11:50:00 EDT"
[21] "2018-06-02 12:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 12:10:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 12:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 12:30:00 EDT"
[25] "2018-06-02 12:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 12:50:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 13:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 13:10:00 EDT"
[29] "2018-06-02 13:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 13:30:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 13:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 13:50:00 EDT"
[33] "2018-06-02 14:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 14:10:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 14:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 14:30:00 EDT"
[37] "2018-06-02 14:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 14:50:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 15:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 15:10:00 EDT"
[41] "2018-06-02 15:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 15:30:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 15:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 15:50:00 EDT"
[45] "2018-06-02 16:00:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 16:10:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 16:20:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 16:30:00 EDT"
[49] "2018-06-02 16:40:00 EDT" "2018-06-02 16:50:00 EDT"
```

I then used the `findInterval` function to get a list of each time frame the columns should fall into.

```
Time_Bins <- findInterval(LDT_Data, LDT_Range)
Time_Bins
[1]  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8
 [39]  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12
 [77] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
[115] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19
[153] 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23
[191] 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 27 27 27 27
[229] 27 27 27 27 27 27 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 31
[267] 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34
[305] 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38
[343] 38 38 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 42 42
[381] 42 42 42 42 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 46 46 46
[419] 46 46 46 46 46 46 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 49 49 49 49 49
```

I am trying to find a way to average the rows together based on the list in the Time_Bins. As shown, the intervals change for the number of samples in each bin that would be averaged. I would like the output to continue to be a dataframe (or a matrix) that contains the same number of rows, but fewer columns that have been averaged together. I have tried and failed using `aggregate` and `rollmean`, but that might be due to errors I have made. Any suggestions to correctly calculate the mean of the rows using the list would be appreciated.

EDIT:
The `dput` of Data:

```
dput(head(APS_DFrame, n = 3))
structure(list(X1 = c("40.3592", "7.80784", "6.17588"), X2 = c("40.4712", 
"7.83984", "6.17588"), X3 = c("38.9112", "7.67985", "6.30387"
), X4 = c("39.3752", "6.59187", "5.72789"), X5 = c("38.3432", 
"7.39185", "5.88788"), X6 = c("39.1712", "6.94386", "5.53589"
), X7 = c("36.4993", "6.91186", "6.01588"), X8 = c("36.1233", 
"6.78386", "5.66389"), X9 = c("35.5713", "6.30387", "5.34389"
), X10 = c("35.8193", "7.51985", "5.72789"), X11 = c("37.9032", 
"6.49587", "5.50389"), X12 = c("37.9792", "7.10386", "6.43187"
), X13 = c("39.3632", "7.55185", "6.62387"), X14 = c("37.7232", 
"6.33587", "5.63189"), X15 = c("37.1833", "7.03986", "5.50389"
), X16 = c("37.4593", "6.97586", "5.2159"), X17 = c("36.8633", 
"6.87986", "6.30387"), X18 = c("34.9913", "6.75187", "5.59989"
), X19 = c("35.7353", "7.03986", "5.91988"), X20 = c("36.4753", 
"7.35985", "5.2479"), X21 = c("36.7553", "6.68787", "5.91988"
), X22 = c("37.6872", "7.83984", "6.43187"), X23 = c("38.2472", 
"7.32785", "5.98388"), X24 = c("37.5352", "7.39185", "5.59989"
), X25 = c("36.4673", "7.32785", "5.95188"), X26 = c("35.7913", 
"7.39185", "6.39987"), X27 = c("35.8793", "6.71987", "5.88788"
), X28 = c("37.5392", "7.07186", "5.69589"), X29 = c("36.9353", 
"7.58385", "5.72789"), X30 = c("37.0913", "7.10386", "5.40789"
), X31 = c("38.3912", "7.29585", "5.47189"), X32 = c("38.6152", 
"7.77584", "6.43187"), X33 = c("38.9952", "7.71185", "5.95188"
), X34 = c("39.8552", "7.55185", "6.39987"), X35 = c("39.4592", 
"7.67985", "6.20788"), X36 = c("38.8232", "7.77584", "6.43187"
), X37 = c("38.8832", "7.71185", "6.87986"), X38 = c("40.5832", 
"6.91186", "6.20788"), X39 = c("39.4912", "7.83984", "6.39987"
), X40 = c("40.1112", "7.07186", "6.27187"), X41 = c("39.7712", 
"6.81586", "6.27187"), X42 = c("39.2152", "7.67985", "6.23988"
), X43 = c("38.5112", "6.91186", "5.91988"), X44 = c("38.1832", 
"6.27187", "5.0559"), X45 = c("37.8352", "6.55987", "5.82388"
), X46 = c("37.6272", "6.91186", "5.75988"), X47 = c("36.8673", 
"6.84786", "5.2159"), X48 = c("37.1673", "6.20788", "6.14388"
), X49 = c("36.7433", "6.65587", "6.30387"), X50 = c("37.3913", 
"7.07186", "5.40789"), X51 = c("36.8473", "6.33587", "5.2479"
), X52 = c("36.2233", "5.98388", "5.31189"), X53 = c("35.8713", 
"5.75988", "4.60791"), X54 = c("35.0633", "6.49587", "5.69589"
), X55 = c("34.2353", "5.66389", "5.56789"), X56 = c("33.2153", 
"5.88788", "5.0559"), X57 = c("33.7993", "5.66389", "4.60791"
), X58 = c("32.1914", "5.1519", "4.51191"), X59 = c("36.6833", 
"5.31189", "5.0239"), X60 = c("36.5073", "5.85588", "4.47991"
), X61 = c("33.5873", "5.40789", "4.8319"), X62 = c("33.3753", 
"5.47189", "4.28791"), X63 = c("32.8633", "4.9279", "4.7679"), 
    X64 = c("32.2794", "5.53589", "4.44791"), X65 = c("31.9194", 
    "5.1199", "4.03192"), X66 = c("31.1274", "4.8319", "4.54391"
    ), X67 = c("29.5954", "4.8639", "3.96792"), X68 = c("29.0194", 
    "5.2479", "3.93592"), X69 = c("29.7994", "4.8639", "3.80792"
    ), X70 = c("29.8114", "5.27989", "3.71193"), X71 = c("29.1674", 
    "4.51191", "3.45593"), X72 = c("29.6034", "5.1519", "4.28791"
    ), X73 = c("30.2754", "5.2479", "4.38391"), X74 = c("30.7194", 
    "5.40789", "4.47991"), X75 = c("31.3234", "5.27989", "4.09592"
    ), X76 = c("32.1714", "4.8319", "5.1519"), X77 = c("33.3873", 
    "5.66389", "4.54391"), X78 = c("34.0153", "5.43989", "5.1519"
    ), X79 = c("34.9673", "6.07988", "4.8959"), X80 = c("35.9513", 
    "5.82388", "4.9919"), X81 = c("35.9833", "5.85588", "4.47991"
    ), X82 = c("36.7633", "5.59989", "4.73591"), X83 = c("37.2873", 
    "6.49587", "5.40789"), X84 = c("37.4913", "7.29585", "4.8959"
    ), X85 = c("37.9872", "6.07988", "5.2159"), X86 = c("39.1032", 
    "6.23988", "5.88788"), X87 = c("39.5592", "7.26385", "5.56789"
    ), X88 = c("38.0472", "7.35985", "5.79188"), X89 = c("37.0073", 
    "6.30387", "5.27989"), X90 = c("36.8673", "6.62387", "5.69589"
    ), X91 = c("37.9592", "6.65587", "5.27989"), X92 = c("39.8352", 
    "7.29585", "5.88788"), X93 = c("38.5152", "6.81586", "5.98388"
    ), X94 = c("38.1112", "8.12784", "6.36787"), X95 = c("39.9032", 
    "6.91186", "5.95188"), X96 = c("40.4592", "6.91186", "5.40789"
    ), X97 = c("39.7072", "7.51985", "6.11188"), X98 = c("39.7592", 
    "7.19986", "5.79188"), X99 = c("40.0112", "7.87184", "5.72789"
    ), X100 = c("38.5552", "8.25583", "6.23988"), X101 = c("38.8872", 
    "6.52787", "5.79188"), X102 = c("39.5152", "7.10386", "5.31189"
    ), X103 = c("38.6632", "7.35985", "6.30387"), X104 = c("38.4552", 
    "8.09584", "6.97586"), X105 = c("38.8912", "6.94386", "6.65587"
    ), X106 = c("38.7112", "7.19986", "5.88788"), X107 = c("38.2312", 
    "6.36787", "5.53589"), X108 = c("38.5712", "7.39185", "6.20788"
    ), X109 = c("38.8112", "6.78386", "6.65587"), X110 = c("38.8672", 
    "7.03986", "6.36787"), X111 = c("38.8072", "6.46387", "6.55987"
    ), X112 = c("39.2432", "7.61585", "6.07988"), X113 = c("39.8792", 
    "7.07186", "6.65587"), X114 = c("39.8112", "7.51985", "5.43989"
    ), X115 = c("40.5872", "7.71185", "6.39987"), X116 = c("41.3432", 
    "7.32785", "6.81586"), X117 = c("40.7512", "7.71185", "7.19986"
    ), X118 = c("41.1272", "7.71185", "5.59989"), X119 = c("40.8032", 
    "8.38383", "6.14388"), X120 = c("40.8712", "7.35985", "6.20788"
    ), X121 = c("40.4752", "6.81586", "5.37589"), X122 = c("39.9152", 
    "6.84786", "5.63189"), X123 = c("40.2392", "6.52787", "5.37589"
    ), X124 = c("40.5592", "6.52787", "5.59989"), X125 = c("40.1952", 
    "7.29585", "6.49587"), X126 = c("40.9712", "7.80784", "6.65587"
    ), X127 = c("41.1712", "7.80784", "6.65587"), X128 = c("41.5992", 
    "7.13586", "6.75187"), X129 = c("40.8672", "7.67985", "6.49587"
    ), X130 = c("40.3432", "6.68787", "5.91988"), X131 = c("41.0072", 
    "7.23186", "5.59989"), X132 = c("40.4872", "8.22384", "6.36787"
    ), X133 = c("41.7392", "7.77584", "6.62387"), X134 = c("42.9031", 
    "8.25583", "7.03986"), X135 = c("42.1792", "8.15984", "6.46387"
    ), X136 = c("41.1312", "7.87184", "6.71987"), X137 = c("42.6231", 
    "8.15984", "6.84786"), X138 = c("43.6991", "7.19986", "6.68787"
    ), X139 = c("44.5391", "7.67985", "7.00786"), X140 = c("43.9231", 
    "8.22384", "6.65587"), X141 = c("43.5631", "8.54383", "6.97586"
    ), X142 = c("44.3271", "7.07186", "6.46387"), X143 = c("45.6311", 
    "8.25583", "7.16786"), X144 = c("45.2191", "8.54383", "7.19986"
    ), X145 = c("46.8351", "8.63983", "7.35985"), X146 = c("46.3991", 
    "8.25583", "7.48785"), X147 = c("47.2311", "8.15984", "7.26385"
    ), X148 = c("47.767", "8.70383", "7.87184"), X149 = c("50.563", 
    "10.0158", "7.93584"), X150 = c("51.515", "9.8238", "8.06384"
    ), X151 = c("49.055", "8.76782", "7.35985"), X152 = c("47.639", 
    "9.24782", "7.48785"), X153 = c("47.775", "9.24782", "7.61585"
    ), X154 = c("48.947", "7.96784", "7.10386"), X155 = c("48.415", 
    "8.57583", "7.32785"), X156 = c("48.031", "8.60783", "7.39185"
    ), X157 = c("47.891", "9.40781", "7.13586"), X158 = c("48.023", 
    "8.15984", "6.39987"), X159 = c("47.615", "9.11982", "8.12784"
    ), X160 = c("46.7191", "8.51183", "7.35985"), X161 = c("47.987", 
    "8.09584", "7.10386"), X162 = c("49.603", "9.05582", "7.96784"
    ), X163 = c("49.631", "8.12784", "7.87184"), X164 = c("49.583", 
    "9.69581", "7.26385"), X165 = c("49.587", "8.57583", "7.55185"
    ), X166 = c("49.063", "8.63983", "7.64785"), X167 = c("47.967", 
    "8.63983", "7.61585"), X168 = c("47.675", "9.18382", "7.90384"
    ), X169 = c("47.595", "7.58385", "7.45585"), X170 = c("47.551", 
    "8.60783", "6.17588"), X171 = c("47.4551", "8.79982", "6.49587"
    ), X172 = c("47.1871", "8.03184", "6.52787"), X173 = c("45.9071", 
    "8.70383", "7.19986"), X174 = c("47.1111", "8.12784", "6.97586"
    ), X175 = c("46.6351", "7.83984", "7.35985"), X176 = c("48.883", 
    "9.11982", "6.78386"), X177 = c("49.559", "8.54383", "7.39185"
    ), X178 = c("49.959", "9.27981", "7.77584"), X179 = c("50.843", 
    "8.92782", "7.61585"), X180 = c("49.419", "9.11982", "7.55185"
    ), X181 = c("48.007", "8.28783", "7.80784"), X182 = c("47.587", 
    "8.89582", "7.80784"), X183 = c("46.2431", "8.54383", "6.94386"
    ), X184 = c("48.159", "7.99984", "8.63983"), X185 = c("46.8471", 
    "8.54383", "6.81586"), X186 = c("47.991", "8.06384", "7.39185"
    ), X187 = c("48.843", "7.96784", "6.97586"), X188 = c("48.771", 
    "8.54383", "7.58385"), X189 = c("48.783", "8.63983", "6.75187"
    ), X190 = c("48.223", "9.02382", "7.64785"), X191 = c("49.111", 
    "8.79982", "7.55185"), X192 = c("47.2511", "8.54383", "6.81586"
    ), X193 = c("47.0031", "8.79982", "7.26385"), X194 = c("47.855", 
    "8.22384", "7.13586"), X195 = c("47.4271", "8.28783", "7.55185"
    ), X196 = c("48.387", "9.05582", "7.48785"), X197 = c("47.1711", 
    "8.60783", "7.67985"), X198 = c("47.0991", "8.63983", "6.68787"
    ), X199 = c("46.3991", "8.54383", "7.39185"), X200 = c("45.7471", 
    "7.83984", "7.13586"), X201 = c("47.1791", "8.25583", "6.65587"
    ), X202 = c("44.7391", "7.71185", "7.23186"), X203 = c("45.5591", 
    "7.99984", "7.16786"), X204 = c("45.9911", "8.92782", "6.65587"
    ), X205 = c("47.2911", "8.51183", "7.42385"), X206 = c("48.875", 
    "8.09584", "6.36787"), X207 = c("47.747", "8.38383", "7.71185"
    ), X208 = c("47.3911", "8.83182", "7.35985"), X209 = c("47.1671", 
    "8.70383", "6.43187"), X210 = c("47.0391", "7.58385", "7.61585"
    ), X211 = c("46.5871", "7.45585", "6.81586"), X212 = c("46.2991", 
    "7.61585", "7.45585"), X213 = c("50.623", "7.93584", "7.10386"
    ), X214 = c("51.903", "8.12784", "7.10386"), X215 = c("52.9349", 
    "8.67183", "7.45585"), X216 = c("51.863", "9.27981", "6.84786"
    ), X217 = c("51.911", "8.63983", "6.75187"), X218 = c("51.655", 
    "8.31983", "8.44783"), X219 = c("51.127", "8.09584", "6.65587"
    ), X220 = c("51.375", "8.57583", "7.07186"), X221 = c("51.255", 
    "9.43981", "7.26385"), X222 = c("51.079", "8.03184", "7.29585"
    ), X223 = c("49.547", "8.03184", "6.97586"), X224 = c("49.855", 
    "8.63983", "6.68787"), X225 = c("49.863", "8.12784", "7.32785"
    ), X226 = c("50.499", "9.08782", "6.27187"), X227 = c("50.243", 
    "7.96784", "6.94386"), X228 = c("50.803", "7.42385", "7.03986"
    ), X229 = c("50.787", "8.38383", "7.48785"), X230 = c("50.259", 
    "8.31983", "6.65587"), X231 = c("51.627", "8.76782", "6.81586"
    ), X232 = c("51.215", "8.57583", "7.45585"), X233 = c("51.295", 
    "8.63983", "6.87986"), X234 = c("50.739", "8.51183", "5.85588"
    ), X235 = c("50.687", "7.67985", "6.91186"), X236 = c("50.131", 
    "7.48785", "6.81586"), X237 = c("49.727", "7.93584", "7.61585"
    ), X238 = c("48.979", "7.35985", "6.91186"), X239 = c("49.835", 
    "7.74385", "6.62387"), X240 = c("49.043", "7.83984", "6.68787"
    ), X241 = c("49.423", "6.62387", "6.33587"), X242 = c("48.547", 
    "8.22384", "7.00786"), X243 = c("49.539", "7.55185", "6.91186"
    ), X244 = c("49.715", "8.76782", "6.94386"), X245 = c("49.483", 
    "7.87184", "6.01588"), X246 = c("48.687", "8.06384", "6.68787"
    ), X247 = c("48.607", "6.91186", "6.46387"), X248 = c("50.063", 
    "8.38383", "6.91186"), X249 = c("49.259", "7.64785", "6.27187"
    ), X250 = c("49.343", "7.29585", "7.16786"), X251 = c("51.343", 
    "8.35183", "6.91186"), X252 = c("52.239", "6.81586", "5.91988"
    ), X253 = c("51.007", "7.77584", "6.81586"), X254 = c("50.331", 
    "8.09584", "6.43187"), X255 = c("50.503", "7.93584", "6.91186"
    ), X256 = c("50.047", "7.74385", "6.49587"), X257 = c("50.343", 
    "7.74385", "6.49587"), X258 = c("50.235", "7.90384", "6.81586"
    ), X259 = c("51.775", "6.81586", "6.68787"), X260 = c("50.699", 
    "7.48785", "6.62387"), X261 = c("51.047", "8.09584", "6.49587"
    ), X262 = c("50.155", "7.74385", "6.65587"), X263 = c("50.303", 
    "6.84786", "7.13586"), X264 = c("51.599", "7.99984", "6.27187"
    ), X265 = c("51.699", "8.73583", "6.62387"), X266 = c("51.551", 
    "8.41583", "6.49587"), X267 = c("52.5549", "8.41583", "6.55987"
    ), X268 = c("52.103", "7.83984", "6.71987"), X269 = c("52.099", 
    "8.95982", "6.17588"), X270 = c("50.763", "8.12784", "7.16786"
    ), X271 = c("51.167", "8.83182", "6.65587"), X272 = c("50.911", 
    "7.67985", "6.71987"), X273 = c("50.559", "7.42385", "7.10386"
    ), X274 = c("53.8109", "7.71185", "7.23186"), X275 = c("54.1389", 
    "8.54383", "6.84786"), X276 = c("51.683", "8.67183", "7.55185"
    ), X277 = c("53.7989", "8.28783", "6.68787"), X278 = c("54.2749", 
    "8.38383", "7.23186"), X279 = c("52.387", "7.55185", "7.07186"
    ), X280 = c("52.459", "8.47983", "6.84786"), X281 = c("52.251", 
    "7.96784", "7.03986"), X282 = c("53.0109", "8.35183", "7.87184"
    ), X283 = c("52.9309", "8.31983", "7.07186"), X284 = c("54.3909", 
    "8.25583", "6.23988"), X285 = c("54.6189", "8.28783", "7.32785"
    ), X286 = c("54.9149", "8.92782", "7.58385"), X287 = c("57.0429", 
    "9.05582", "7.00786"), X288 = c("56.7749", "8.92782", "7.83984"
    ), X289 = c("57.8508", "9.8238", "7.35985"), X290 = c("58.7868", 
    "8.57583", "7.26385"), X291 = c("59.3148", "9.66381", "8.22384"
    ), X292 = c("59.5148", "9.27981", "7.16786"), X293 = c("60.4348", 
    "10.0158", "7.93584"), X294 = c("61.1748", "9.08782", "8.28783"
    ), X295 = c("62.6427", "8.76782", "7.51985"), X296 = c("60.9108", 
    "10.3998", "7.87184"), X297 = c("60.8868", "8.92782", "8.19184"
    ), X298 = c("60.7188", "10.2078", "7.48785"), X299 = c("61.1988", 
    "8.89582", "7.45585"), X300 = c("61.0188", "9.7918", "8.03184"
    ), X301 = c("62.9347", "9.9838", "8.31983"), X302 = c("62.6347", 
    "9.8558", "8.54383"), X303 = c("63.0747", "9.47181", "8.22384"
    ), X304 = c("65.2387", "10.3678", "8.95982"), X305 = c("66.0147", 
    "11.0078", "8.35183"), X306 = c("66.3107", "10.6878", "8.67183"
    ), X307 = c("66.3187", "11.2958", "8.03184"), X308 = c("65.9627", 
    "9.43981", "8.57583"), X309 = c("66.7547", "10.3038", "7.99984"
    ), X310 = c("66.5427", "11.8718", "9.18382"), X311 = c("68.2266", 
    "9.8558", "9.08782"), X312 = c("68.3826", "10.6878", "8.28783"
    ), X313 = c("66.4067", "11.0078", "8.99182"), X314 = c("65.0107", 
    "10.0478", "8.31983"), X315 = c("66.3747", "10.9438", "8.95982"
    ), X316 = c("68.0266", "10.3998", "8.67183"), X317 = c("68.3226", 
    "10.8158", "9.02382"), X318 = c("68.7706", "11.2958", "9.24782"
    ), X319 = c("68.9466", "11.3598", "9.7598"), X320 = c("69.5546", 
    "10.1118", "9.18382"), X321 = c("69.9106", "11.1358", "8.95982"
    ), X322 = c("69.6186", "11.8078", "8.99182"), X323 = c("69.6906", 
    "11.3598", "8.99182"), X324 = c("70.0666", "10.4318", "9.9838"
    ), X325 = c("71.4426", "11.9358", "10.0798"), X326 = c("70.6906", 
    "10.3038", "9.50381"), X327 = c("70.5226", "11.8078", "9.63181"
    ), X328 = c("71.4426", "11.5518", "9.05582"), X329 = c("71.3066", 
    "11.3278", "9.02382"), X330 = c("73.7305", "11.4878", "8.60783"
    ), X331 = c("74.5185", "10.7838", "9.66381"), X332 = c("75.3585", 
    "11.6478", "10.2078"), X333 = c("74.1065", "11.7758", "9.21582"
    ), X334 = c("73.2185", "12.6397", "9.9838"), X335 = c("72.8905", 
    "13.0557", "9.50381"), X336 = c("74.8425", "12.5757", "10.0798"
    ), X337 = c("75.7425", "12.0638", "9.59981"), X338 = c("68.1106", 
    "11.4558", "9.63181"), X339 = c("66.5347", "12.0638", "11.4878"
    ), X340 = c("67.7226", "11.9358", "10.3358"), X341 = c("68.5066", 
    "12.4798", "10.5598"), X342 = c("69.8426", "12.3198", "10.5918"
    ), X343 = c("69.3426", "12.4478", "11.6798"), X344 = c("69.5506", 
    "12.3198", "10.4638"), X345 = c("70.6106", "12.6077", "11.4878"
    ), X346 = c("70.2346", "12.5757", "9.9198"), X347 = c("71.5106", 
    "12.9277", "10.8798"), X348 = c("71.4706", "13.1197", "10.8478"
    ), X349 = c("71.8026", "12.9277", "10.4958"), X350 = c("72.3826", 
    "12.5437", "10.4318"), X351 = c("71.4106", "12.9597", "11.1678"
    ), X352 = c("71.6746", "12.8317", "10.4638"), X353 = c("72.9185", 
    "12.8317", "10.8478"), X354 = c("71.1786", "14.0797", "10.7838"
    ), X355 = c("71.1066", "13.9517", "10.5278"), X356 = c("69.5986", 
    "12.2878", "10.2078"), X357 = c("70.1186", "12.5437", "10.4958"
    ), X358 = c("71.2186", "13.2477", "10.2718"), X359 = c("70.7306", 
    "12.7357", "10.8158"), X360 = c("69.9226", "13.7597", "10.3998"
    ), X361 = c("69.2346", "13.0877", "10.8798"), X362 = c("71.4666", 
    "13.9197", "10.3038"), X363 = c("70.4466", "12.6397", "9.56781"
    ), X364 = c("70.7466", "12.5437", "10.8798"), X365 = c("71.0586", 
    "13.7917", "10.9118"), X366 = c("70.7946", "13.7917", "10.4638"
    ), X367 = c("71.4546", "13.0877", "11.2958"), X368 = c("72.0826", 
    "14.0477", "11.3278"), X369 = c("72.2946", "12.8957", "10.8798"
    ), X370 = c("72.5306", "13.8557", "10.2718"), X371 = c("72.7465", 
    "13.0237", "11.9678"), X372 = c("74.7305", "13.9837", "10.9118"
    ), X373 = c("73.3705", "13.1197", "9.8878"), X374 = c("73.6345", 
    "12.2878", "10.8798"), X375 = c("74.3105", "13.3437", "11.1678"
    ), X376 = c("74.3545", "12.7037", "11.0078"), X377 = c("74.6865", 
    "11.9358", "10.9118"), X378 = c("74.2625", "13.3117", "10.4318"
    ), X379 = c("73.4585", "13.5997", "10.3358"), X380 = c("75.9545", 
    "12.8957", "10.6878"), X381 = c("74.2065", "12.6077", "10.5278"
    ), X382 = c("73.4785", "11.4878", "10.0158"), X383 = c("72.4066", 
    "12.2558", "10.1118"), X384 = c("72.9025", "12.6077", "11.2638"
    ), X385 = c("73.4505", "12.6717", "10.5598"), X386 = c("72.6425", 
    "12.9597", "10.1758"), X387 = c("72.4026", "11.9998", "9.8558"
    ), X388 = c("73.0025", "12.3198", "10.2398"), X389 = c("72.3866", 
    "12.4158", "10.0798"), X390 = c("65.4147", "10.5278", "8.38383"
    ), X391 = c("55.4749", "9.37581", "7.67985"), X392 = c("54.0749", 
    "9.31181", "7.58385"), X393 = c("52.9269", "9.47181", "7.00786"
    ), X394 = c("53.3669", "10.1438", "8.35183"), X395 = c("55.5429", 
    "9.7598", "7.55185"), X396 = c("56.4589", "10.1438", "7.23186"
    ), X397 = c("57.4109", "10.2718", "8.25583"), X398 = c("58.7708", 
    "11.0718", "7.99984"), X399 = c("60.4588", "10.7198", "8.60783"
    ), X400 = c("63.1027", "10.5278", "9.27981"), X401 = c("64.7667", 
    "11.4238", "10.1118"), X402 = c("61.7748", "9.59981", "8.83182"
    ), X403 = c("60.3028", "10.5598", "8.44783"), X404 = c("62.9307", 
    "10.9758", "10.1118"), X405 = c("64.8587", "11.8078", "9.66381"
    ), X406 = c("66.4707", "11.7758", "11.3598"), X407 = c("67.2467", 
    "12.7037", "11.0398"), X408 = c("69.0506", "13.3757", "9.9838"
    ), X409 = c("69.3546", "12.7677", "10.3038"), X410 = c("70.7386", 
    "13.3437", "10.5598"), X411 = c("72.3306", "13.3117", "11.9998"
    ), X412 = c("72.3586", "14.9437", "11.1358"), X413 = c("72.0746", 
    "14.4317", "11.6478"), X414 = c("71.5946", "14.4317", "12.0638"
    ), X415 = c("70.9106", "13.7597", "11.6158"), X416 = c("68.6306", 
    "12.7677", "11.0078"), X417 = c("67.6026", "13.5037", "11.5198"
    ), X418 = c("67.3787", "12.3838", "11.2318"), X419 = c("66.3187", 
    "12.4798", "11.0078"), X420 = c("65.5987", "13.1517", "10.3998"
    ), X421 = c("64.9427", "13.2477", "9.9838"), X422 = c("64.3667", 
    "12.3838", "10.9438"), X423 = c("63.3507", "12.4478", "10.3038"
    ), X424 = c("61.5668", "12.6077", "10.3358"), X425 = c("59.2788", 
    "12.7357", "10.2718"), X426 = c("58.4828", "12.4478", "10.3678"
    ), X427 = c("56.2229", "11.6158", "10.0798"), X428 = c("56.2349", 
    "11.9358", "9.9198"), X429 = c("54.3309", "11.9678", "10.2398"
    ), X430 = c("50.011", "10.1438", "9.43981"), X431 = c("49.143", 
    "11.2958", "10.1118"), X432 = c("48.107", "9.50381", "8.79982"
    ), X433 = c("46.7871", "9.31181", "8.31983"), X434 = c("49.999", 
    "9.8558", "9.72781"), X435 = c("42.5152", "9.53581", "7.67985"
    ), X436 = c("29.9394", "7.29585", "5.72789"), X437 = c("28.0914", 
    "7.93584", "5.72789"), X438 = c("26.5035", "7.39185", "5.72789"
    ), X439 = c("21.2156", "6.91186", "5.88788"), X440 = c("18.7756", 
    "6.11188", "6.11188"), X441 = c("18.9236", "7.03986", "5.82388"
    ), X442 = c("17.4917", "6.75187", "5.88788"), X443 = c("17.2317", 
    "5.72789", "4.63991"), X444 = c("13.6757", "5.63189", "4.73591"
    ), X445 = c("12.8197", "5.75988", "5.0879"), X446 = c("12.6117", 
    "6.23988", "5.50389"), X447 = c("17.7676", "7.10386", "6.43187"
    ), X448 = c("14.3597", "7.07186", "6.39987"), X449 = c("14.5877", 
    "6.81586", "6.46387")), row.names = 4:6, class = "data.frame")
```

The class of `Time_Bins` is `integer`.

The desired outcome would be for the columns of `Data` to be averaged with all the other columns that share the same value in `Time_Bins`. Due to character limitations, I removed the first table showing the data.

```
Desired_Result
row 1     Mean first 4 columns      Mean of all columns with 5 in `Time_Bins` ... etc
row 2     Mean first 4 columns      Mean of all columns with 5 in `Time_Bins` ... etc
... etc
```

Comment for addition info to be provided.

Comment: @akrun `LDT_Data` is the the local date time of when the samples were taken. I did not include it above, but used it to get the `Sampling_Start` and `Sampling_Stop` used in `LDT_Range`. I can edit the post to include that if it will be beneficial.

Comment: No, `Data` is long and contains over 50 rows. I only included the first 2 rows here as examples of the data. Each column corresponds to a data collection time and each row represents data collected during that period.

Comment: `list` is the `Time_Bins` in this instance. The numbers in `Time_Bins` correspond to the 10 minute interval in `LDT_Range` that the sample was collected. so the `4` represents "2018-06-02 09:10:00 EDT"

Comment: I tested the above code and it gave a 1:46 vector of NA

Comment: The code had the same result of NA in a vector.

Comment: Sorry, the class of `Time_Bins` is "integer".

Comment: Yes, after doing `str(Data)` the output is: 'Data.frame': 52 obs. of 449 variables:

Comment: The output is `FALSE`. When opening the files from the software there are rows that contained words/sentences, but those have previously been removed.

Comment: The code did not seem to work properly using either option. This produced a vector of 45 objects where the first 5 have numbers and the rest have NAN.

Comment: This provides the same answer as previous. All but 5 of the results are filled with NAN

Comment: Hi @TCBatUGA. I struggle to make sense of the code you give and the comments. Would you mind tidying up your question and include critical information from the comments in the main post? For example, in your post you mention `LDT_Data` but I can only see `Data`. `Sampling_Start` and `Sampling_Stop` are not defined anywhere. As such your [example code is not reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I would recommend editing your post to include a truly *minimal* example (surely you don't need 449 columns) including expected output.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Hi, I just updated the post with some more information about the `dput` as suggested by someone. Due to the character limit, I could not input all of the data but can try to explain it and can try to post it if necessary! The `LDT_Data` is the times samples were measured. `Sampling_Start` and `Sampling_Stop` are from performing `min` and `max` on the `LDT_Data`.  I will update the post with fewer columns if that would be helpful and can tag you in a comment of you are interested in looking at it again.

Comment: @akrun The desired result isn't to receive a vector, but a dataframe the same number of rows as previously held in `Data` but with fewer columns from averaging the rows of columns that share the same number in `Time_Bins`. So instead of having a dataframe that is 52 x 449, it will be 52 x 45 (49-4)

Comment: @akrun, Sorry I had to step away for a meeting, but the solution you posted is correct and solved the question I had. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, we `split` the sequence of `Data` by 'Time_Bins', loop over the `list`, subset the columns, and get the `rowMeans`

```
sapply(split(seq_along(Data), Time_Bins), function(i) 
        rowMeans(sapply(Data[, i], as.numeric), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
      4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16
[1,] 39.77920 37.449640 36.893270 37.556050 39.303200 36.763680 33.873720 30.103800 34.934120 38.299220 39.391600 38.982400 40.667200
[2,]  7.47985  6.934260  7.129457  7.353453  7.267054  6.483070  5.487890  5.052699  5.836682  6.876662  7.375852  7.039859  7.292654
[3,]  6.09588  5.836684  5.772685  5.932681  6.188676  5.551889  4.758304  4.060718  4.835104  5.695885  5.961480  6.204677  6.035080
            17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29
[1,] 41.128390 43.683520 48.372630 48.349810 47.709840 48.529420 48.067830 46.569890 48.092260 51.260190 50.733000 49.562600 50.036200
[2,]  7.590248  7.971042  8.883023  8.735827  8.489432  8.655826  8.515030  8.387032  8.124638  8.572629  8.380632  7.721446  7.721444
[3,]  6.460672  6.819065  7.555048  7.395051  7.155058  7.567847  7.193456  7.164659  7.139057  7.145457  6.873461  6.876662  6.559868
            30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37       38       39       40       41       42        43
[1,] 50.670600 51.721780 53.132540 58.042840 62.125950 66.593080 68.928210 72.633750 70.30858 71.51939 70.45900 72.46976 74.00211 64.514300
[2,]  7.631848  8.214236  8.281433  9.164616  9.667007 10.620601 10.966200 11.526190 12.27178 12.94050 13.07171 13.38851 12.67493 11.119783
[3,]  6.659067  6.745468  7.046260  7.599847  8.060639  8.550229  9.177417  9.497412 10.39340 10.73260 10.43500 10.87980 10.64620  8.991822
            44       45       46        47        48        49
[1,] 60.152000 69.60783 66.06668 52.859740 23.436340 14.429280
[2,] 10.505401 13.28932 12.87334 11.081392  7.033460  6.598268
[3,]  8.643027 10.97580 10.83500  9.727807  5.795086  5.977480
```

---

Or use `split.default`

```
sapply(split.default(Data, Time_Bins), 
     function(x) rowMeans(sapply(x, as.numeric), na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
Time_Bins <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49)

Data <- structure(list(X1 = c("40.3592", "7.80784", "6.17588"), X2 = c("40.4712", 
"7.83984", "6.17588"), X3 = c("38.9112", "7.67985", "6.30387"
), X4 = c("39.3752", "6.59187", "5.72789"), X5 = c("38.3432", 
"7.39185", "5.88788"), X6 = c("39.1712", "6.94386", "5.53589"
), X7 = c("36.4993", "6.91186", "6.01588"), X8 = c("36.1233", 
"6.78386", "5.66389"), X9 = c("35.5713", "6.30387", "5.34389"
), X10 = c("35.8193", "7.51985", "5.72789"), X11 = c("37.9032", 
"6.49587", "5.50389"), X12 = c("37.9792", "7.10386", "6.43187"
), X13 = c("39.3632", "7.55185", "6.62387"), X14 = c("37.7232", 
"6.33587", "5.63189"), X15 = c("37.1833", "7.03986", "5.50389"
), X16 = c("37.4593", "6.97586", "5.2159"), X17 = c("36.8633", 
"6.87986", "6.30387"), X18 = c("34.9913", "6.75187", "5.59989"
), X19 = c("35.7353", "7.03986", "5.91988"), X20 = c("36.4753", 
"7.35985", "5.2479"), X21 = c("36.7553", "6.68787", "5.91988"
), X22 = c("37.6872", "7.83984", "6.43187"), X23 = c("38.2472", 
"7.32785", "5.98388"), X24 = c("37.5352", "7.39185", "5.59989"
), X25 = c("36.4673", "7.32785", "5.95188"), X26 = c("35.7913", 
"7.39185", "6.39987"), X27 = c("35.8793", "6.71987", "5.88788"
), X28 = c("37.5392", "7.07186", "5.69589"), X29 = c("36.9353", 
"7.58385", "5.72789"), X30 = c("37.0913", "7.10386", "5.40789"
), X31 = c("38.3912", "7.29585", "5.47189"), X32 = c("38.6152", 
"7.77584", "6.43187"), X33 = c("38.9952", "7.71185", "5.95188"
), X34 = c("39.8552", "7.55185", "6.39987"), X35 = c("39.4592", 
"7.67985", "6.20788"), X36 = c("38.8232", "7.77584", "6.43187"
), X37 = c("38.8832", "7.71185", "6.87986"), X38 = c("40.5832", 
"6.91186", "6.20788"), X39 = c("39.4912", "7.83984", "6.39987"
), X40 = c("40.1112", "7.07186", "6.27187"), X41 = c("39.7712", 
"6.81586", "6.27187"), X42 = c("39.2152", "7.67985", "6.23988"
), X43 = c("38.5112", "6.91186", "5.91988"), X44 = c("38.1832", 
"6.27187", "5.0559"), X45 = c("37.8352", "6.55987", "5.82388"
), X46 = c("37.6272", "6.91186", "5.75988"), X47 = c("36.8673", 
"6.84786", "5.2159"), X48 = c("37.1673", "6.20788", "6.14388"
), X49 = c("36.7433", "6.65587", "6.30387"), X50 = c("37.3913", 
"7.07186", "5.40789"), X51 = c("36.8473", "6.33587", "5.2479"
), X52 = c("36.2233", "5.98388", "5.31189"), X53 = c("35.8713", 
"5.75988", "4.60791"), X54 = c("35.0633", "6.49587", "5.69589"
), X55 = c("34.2353", "5.66389", "5.56789"), X56 = c("33.2153", 
"5.88788", "5.0559"), X57 = c("33.7993", "5.66389", "4.60791"
), X58 = c("32.1914", "5.1519", "4.51191"), X59 = c("36.6833", 
"5.31189", "5.0239"), X60 = c("36.5073", "5.85588", "4.47991"
), X61 = c("33.5873", "5.40789", "4.8319"), X62 = c("33.3753", 
"5.47189", "4.28791"), X63 = c("32.8633", "4.9279", "4.7679"), 
    X64 = c("32.2794", "5.53589", "4.44791"), X65 = c("31.9194", 
    "5.1199", "4.03192"), X66 = c("31.1274", "4.8319", "4.54391"
    ), X67 = c("29.5954", "4.8639", "3.96792"), X68 = c("29.0194", 
    "5.2479", "3.93592"), X69 = c("29.7994", "4.8639", "3.80792"
    ), X70 = c("29.8114", "5.27989", "3.71193"), X71 = c("29.1674", 
    "4.51191", "3.45593"), X72 = c("29.6034", "5.1519", "4.28791"
    ), X73 = c("30.2754", "5.2479", "4.38391"), X74 = c("30.7194", 
    "5.40789", "4.47991"), X75 = c("31.3234", "5.27989", "4.09592"
    ), X76 = c("32.1714", "4.8319", "5.1519"), X77 = c("33.3873", 
    "5.66389", "4.54391"), X78 = c("34.0153", "5.43989", "5.1519"
    ), X79 = c("34.9673", "6.07988", "4.8959"), X80 = c("35.9513", 
    "5.82388", "4.9919"), X81 = c("35.9833", "5.85588", "4.47991"
    ), X82 = c("36.7633", "5.59989", "4.73591"), X83 = c("37.2873", 
    "6.49587", "5.40789"), X84 = c("37.4913", "7.29585", "4.8959"
    ), X85 = c("37.9872", "6.07988", "5.2159"), X86 = c("39.1032", 
    "6.23988", "5.88788"), X87 = c("39.5592", "7.26385", "5.56789"
    ), X88 = c("38.0472", "7.35985", "5.79188"), X89 = c("37.0073", 
    "6.30387", "5.27989"), X90 = c("36.8673", "6.62387", "5.69589"
    ), X91 = c("37.9592", "6.65587", "5.27989"), X92 = c("39.8352", 
    "7.29585", "5.88788"), X93 = c("38.5152", "6.81586", "5.98388"
    ), X94 = c("38.1112", "8.12784", "6.36787"), X95 = c("39.9032", 
    "6.91186", "5.95188"), X96 = c("40.4592", "6.91186", "5.40789"
    ), X97 = c("39.7072", "7.51985", "6.11188"), X98 = c("39.7592", 
    "7.19986", "5.79188"), X99 = c("40.0112", "7.87184", "5.72789"
    ), X100 = c("38.5552", "8.25583", "6.23988"), X101 = c("38.8872", 
    "6.52787", "5.79188"), X102 = c("39.5152", "7.10386", "5.31189"
    ), X103 = c("38.6632", "7.35985", "6.30387"), X104 = c("38.4552", 
    "8.09584", "6.97586"), X105 = c("38.8912", "6.94386", "6.65587"
    ), X106 = c("38.7112", "7.19986", "5.88788"), X107 = c("38.2312", 
    "6.36787", "5.53589"), X108 = c("38.5712", "7.39185", "6.20788"
    ), X109 = c("38.8112", "6.78386", "6.65587"), X110 = c("38.8672", 
    "7.03986", "6.36787"), X111 = c("38.8072", "6.46387", "6.55987"
    ), X112 = c("39.2432", "7.61585", "6.07988"), X113 = c("39.8792", 
    "7.07186", "6.65587"), X114 = c("39.8112", "7.51985", "5.43989"
    ), X115 = c("40.5872", "7.71185", "6.39987"), X116 = c("41.3432", 
    "7.32785", "6.81586"), X117 = c("40.7512", "7.71185", "7.19986"
    ), X118 = c("41.1272", "7.71185", "5.59989"), X119 = c("40.8032", 
    "8.38383", "6.14388"), X120 = c("40.8712", "7.35985", "6.20788"
    ), X121 = c("40.4752", "6.81586", "5.37589"), X122 = c("39.9152", 
    "6.84786", "5.63189"), X123 = c("40.2392", "6.52787", "5.37589"
    ), X124 = c("40.5592", "6.52787", "5.59989"), X125 = c("40.1952", 
    "7.29585", "6.49587"), X126 = c("40.9712", "7.80784", "6.65587"
    ), X127 = c("41.1712", "7.80784", "6.65587"), X128 = c("41.5992", 
    "7.13586", "6.75187"), X129 = c("40.8672", "7.67985", "6.49587"
    ), X130 = c("40.3432", "6.68787", "5.91988"), X131 = c("41.0072", 
    "7.23186", "5.59989"), X132 = c("40.4872", "8.22384", "6.36787"
    ), X133 = c("41.7392", "7.77584", "6.62387"), X134 = c("42.9031", 
    "8.25583", "7.03986"), X135 = c("42.1792", "8.15984", "6.46387"
    ), X136 = c("41.1312", "7.87184", "6.71987"), X137 = c("42.6231", 
    "8.15984", "6.84786"), X138 = c("43.6991", "7.19986", "6.68787"
    ), X139 = c("44.5391", "7.67985", "7.00786"), X140 = c("43.9231", 
    "8.22384", "6.65587"), X141 = c("43.5631", "8.54383", "6.97586"
    ), X142 = c("44.3271", "7.07186", "6.46387"), X143 = c("45.6311", 
    "8.25583", "7.16786"), X144 = c("45.2191", "8.54383", "7.19986"
    ), X145 = c("46.8351", "8.63983", "7.35985"), X146 = c("46.3991", 
    "8.25583", "7.48785"), X147 = c("47.2311", "8.15984", "7.26385"
    ), X148 = c("47.767", "8.70383", "7.87184"), X149 = c("50.563", 
    "10.0158", "7.93584"), X150 = c("51.515", "9.8238", "8.06384"
    ), X151 = c("49.055", "8.76782", "7.35985"), X152 = c("47.639", 
    "9.24782", "7.48785"), X153 = c("47.775", "9.24782", "7.61585"
    ), X154 = c("48.947", "7.96784", "7.10386"), X155 = c("48.415", 
    "8.57583", "7.32785"), X156 = c("48.031", "8.60783", "7.39185"
    ), X157 = c("47.891", "9.40781", "7.13586"), X158 = c("48.023", 
    "8.15984", "6.39987"), X159 = c("47.615", "9.11982", "8.12784"
    ), X160 = c("46.7191", "8.51183", "7.35985"), X161 = c("47.987", 
    "8.09584", "7.10386"), X162 = c("49.603", "9.05582", "7.96784"
    ), X163 = c("49.631", "8.12784", "7.87184"), X164 = c("49.583", 
    "9.69581", "7.26385"), X165 = c("49.587", "8.57583", "7.55185"
    ), X166 = c("49.063", "8.63983", "7.64785"), X167 = c("47.967", 
    "8.63983", "7.61585"), X168 = c("47.675", "9.18382", "7.90384"
    ), X169 = c("47.595", "7.58385", "7.45585"), X170 = c("47.551", 
    "8.60783", "6.17588"), X171 = c("47.4551", "8.79982", "6.49587"
    ), X172 = c("47.1871", "8.03184", "6.52787"), X173 = c("45.9071", 
    "8.70383", "7.19986"), X174 = c("47.1111", "8.12784", "6.97586"
    ), X175 = c("46.6351", "7.83984", "7.35985"), X176 = c("48.883", 
    "9.11982", "6.78386"), X177 = c("49.559", "8.54383", "7.39185"
    ), X178 = c("49.959", "9.27981", "7.77584"), X179 = c("50.843", 
    "8.92782", "7.61585"), X180 = c("49.419", "9.11982", "7.55185"
    ), X181 = c("48.007", "8.28783", "7.80784"), X182 = c("47.587", 
    "8.89582", "7.80784"), X183 = c("46.2431", "8.54383", "6.94386"
    ), X184 = c("48.159", "7.99984", "8.63983"), X185 = c("46.8471", 
    "8.54383", "6.81586"), X186 = c("47.991", "8.06384", "7.39185"
    ), X187 = c("48.843", "7.96784", "6.97586"), X188 = c("48.771", 
    "8.54383", "7.58385"), X189 = c("48.783", "8.63983", "6.75187"
    ), X190 = c("48.223", "9.02382", "7.64785"), X191 = c("49.111", 
    "8.79982", "7.55185"), X192 = c("47.2511", "8.54383", "6.81586"
    ), X193 = c("47.0031", "8.79982", "7.26385"), X194 = c("47.855", 
    "8.22384", "7.13586"), X195 = c("47.4271", "8.28783", "7.55185"
    ), X196 = c("48.387", "9.05582", "7.48785"), X197 = c("47.1711", 
    "8.60783", "7.67985"), X198 = c("47.0991", "8.63983", "6.68787"
    ), X199 = c("46.3991", "8.54383", "7.39185"), X200 = c("45.7471", 
    "7.83984", "7.13586"), X201 = c("47.1791", "8.25583", "6.65587"
    ), X202 = c("44.7391", "7.71185", "7.23186"), X203 = c("45.5591", 
    "7.99984", "7.16786"), X204 = c("45.9911", "8.92782", "6.65587"
    ), X205 = c("47.2911", "8.51183", "7.42385"), X206 = c("48.875", 
    "8.09584", "6.36787"), X207 = c("47.747", "8.38383", "7.71185"
    ), X208 = c("47.3911", "8.83182", "7.35985"), X209 = c("47.1671", 
    "8.70383", "6.43187"), X210 = c("47.0391", "7.58385", "7.61585"
    ), X211 = c("46.5871", "7.45585", "6.81586"), X212 = c("46.2991", 
    "7.61585", "7.45585"), X213 = c("50.623", "7.93584", "7.10386"
    ), X214 = c("51.903", "8.12784", "7.10386"), X215 = c("52.9349", 
    "8.67183", "7.45585"), X216 = c("51.863", "9.27981", "6.84786"
    ), X217 = c("51.911", "8.63983", "6.75187"), X218 = c("51.655", 
    "8.31983", "8.44783"), X219 = c("51.127", "8.09584", "6.65587"
    ), X220 = c("51.375", "8.57583", "7.07186"), X221 = c("51.255", 
    "9.43981", "7.26385"), X222 = c("51.079", "8.03184", "7.29585"
    ), X223 = c("49.547", "8.03184", "6.97586"), X224 = c("49.855", 
    "8.63983", "6.68787"), X225 = c("49.863", "8.12784", "7.32785"
    ), X226 = c("50.499", "9.08782", "6.27187"), X227 = c("50.243", 
    "7.96784", "6.94386"), X228 = c("50.803", "7.42385", "7.03986"
    ), X229 = c("50.787", "8.38383", "7.48785"), X230 = c("50.259", 
    "8.31983", "6.65587"), X231 = c("51.627", "8.76782", "6.81586"
    ), X232 = c("51.215", "8.57583", "7.45585"), X233 = c("51.295", 
    "8.63983", "6.87986"), X234 = c("50.739", "8.51183", "5.85588"
    ), X235 = c("50.687", "7.67985", "6.91186"), X236 = c("50.131", 
    "7.48785", "6.81586"), X237 = c("49.727", "7.93584", "7.61585"
    ), X238 = c("48.979", "7.35985", "6.91186"), X239 = c("49.835", 
    "7.74385", "6.62387"), X240 = c("49.043", "7.83984", "6.68787"
    ), X241 = c("49.423", "6.62387", "6.33587"), X242 = c("48.547", 
    "8.22384", "7.00786"), X243 = c("49.539", "7.55185", "6.91186"
    ), X244 = c("49.715", "8.76782", "6.94386"), X245 = c("49.483", 
    "7.87184", "6.01588"), X246 = c("48.687", "8.06384", "6.68787"
    ), X247 = c("48.607", "6.91186", "6.46387"), X248 = c("50.063", 
    "8.38383", "6.91186"), X249 = c("49.259", "7.64785", "6.27187"
    ), X250 = c("49.343", "7.29585", "7.16786"), X251 = c("51.343", 
    "8.35183", "6.91186"), X252 = c("52.239", "6.81586", "5.91988"
    ), X253 = c("51.007", "7.77584", "6.81586"), X254 = c("50.331", 
    "8.09584", "6.43187"), X255 = c("50.503", "7.93584", "6.91186"
    ), X256 = c("50.047", "7.74385", "6.49587"), X257 = c("50.343", 
    "7.74385", "6.49587"), X258 = c("50.235", "7.90384", "6.81586"
    ), X259 = c("51.775", "6.81586", "6.68787"), X260 = c("50.699", 
    "7.48785", "6.62387"), X261 = c("51.047", "8.09584", "6.49587"
    ), X262 = c("50.155", "7.74385", "6.65587"), X263 = c("50.303", 
    "6.84786", "7.13586"), X264 = c("51.599", "7.99984", "6.27187"
    ), X265 = c("51.699", "8.73583", "6.62387"), X266 = c("51.551", 
    "8.41583", "6.49587"), X267 = c("52.5549", "8.41583", "6.55987"
    ), X268 = c("52.103", "7.83984", "6.71987"), X269 = c("52.099", 
    "8.95982", "6.17588"), X270 = c("50.763", "8.12784", "7.16786"
    ), X271 = c("51.167", "8.83182", "6.65587"), X272 = c("50.911", 
    "7.67985", "6.71987"), X273 = c("50.559", "7.42385", "7.10386"
    ), X274 = c("53.8109", "7.71185", "7.23186"), X275 = c("54.1389", 
    "8.54383", "6.84786"), X276 = c("51.683", "8.67183", "7.55185"
    ), X277 = c("53.7989", "8.28783", "6.68787"), X278 = c("54.2749", 
    "8.38383", "7.23186"), X279 = c("52.387", "7.55185", "7.07186"
    ), X280 = c("52.459", "8.47983", "6.84786"), X281 = c("52.251", 
    "7.96784", "7.03986"), X282 = c("53.0109", "8.35183", "7.87184"
    ), X283 = c("52.9309", "8.31983", "7.07186"), X284 = c("54.3909", 
    "8.25583", "6.23988"), X285 = c("54.6189", "8.28783", "7.32785"
    ), X286 = c("54.9149", "8.92782", "7.58385"), X287 = c("57.0429", 
    "9.05582", "7.00786"), X288 = c("56.7749", "8.92782", "7.83984"
    ), X289 = c("57.8508", "9.8238", "7.35985"), X290 = c("58.7868", 
    "8.57583", "7.26385"), X291 = c("59.3148", "9.66381", "8.22384"
    ), X292 = c("59.5148", "9.27981", "7.16786"), X293 = c("60.4348", 
    "10.0158", "7.93584"), X294 = c("61.1748", "9.08782", "8.28783"
    ), X295 = c("62.6427", "8.76782", "7.51985"), X296 = c("60.9108", 
    "10.3998", "7.87184"), X297 = c("60.8868", "8.92782", "8.19184"
    ), X298 = c("60.7188", "10.2078", "7.48785"), X299 = c("61.1988", 
    "8.89582", "7.45585"), X300 = c("61.0188", "9.7918", "8.03184"
    ), X301 = c("62.9347", "9.9838", "8.31983"), X302 = c("62.6347", 
    "9.8558", "8.54383"), X303 = c("63.0747", "9.47181", "8.22384"
    ), X304 = c("65.2387", "10.3678", "8.95982"), X305 = c("66.0147", 
    "11.0078", "8.35183"), X306 = c("66.3107", "10.6878", "8.67183"
    ), X307 = c("66.3187", "11.2958", "8.03184"), X308 = c("65.9627", 
    "9.43981", "8.57583"), X309 = c("66.7547", "10.3038", "7.99984"
    ), X310 = c("66.5427", "11.8718", "9.18382"), X311 = c("68.2266", 
    "9.8558", "9.08782"), X312 = c("68.3826", "10.6878", "8.28783"
    ), X313 = c("66.4067", "11.0078", "8.99182"), X314 = c("65.0107", 
    "10.0478", "8.31983"), X315 = c("66.3747", "10.9438", "8.95982"
    ), X316 = c("68.0266", "10.3998", "8.67183"), X317 = c("68.3226", 
    "10.8158", "9.02382"), X318 = c("68.7706", "11.2958", "9.24782"
    ), X319 = c("68.9466", "11.3598", "9.7598"), X320 = c("69.5546", 
    "10.1118", "9.18382"), X321 = c("69.9106", "11.1358", "8.95982"
    ), X322 = c("69.6186", "11.8078", "8.99182"), X323 = c("69.6906", 
    "11.3598", "8.99182"), X324 = c("70.0666", "10.4318", "9.9838"
    ), X325 = c("71.4426", "11.9358", "10.0798"), X326 = c("70.6906", 
    "10.3038", "9.50381"), X327 = c("70.5226", "11.8078", "9.63181"
    ), X328 = c("71.4426", "11.5518", "9.05582"), X329 = c("71.3066", 
    "11.3278", "9.02382"), X330 = c("73.7305", "11.4878", "8.60783"
    ), X331 = c("74.5185", "10.7838", "9.66381"), X332 = c("75.3585", 
    "11.6478", "10.2078"), X333 = c("74.1065", "11.7758", "9.21582"
    ), X334 = c("73.2185", "12.6397", "9.9838"), X335 = c("72.8905", 
    "13.0557", "9.50381"), X336 = c("74.8425", "12.5757", "10.0798"
    ), X337 = c("75.7425", "12.0638", "9.59981"), X338 = c("68.1106", 
    "11.4558", "9.63181"), X339 = c("66.5347", "12.0638", "11.4878"
    ), X340 = c("67.7226", "11.9358", "10.3358"), X341 = c("68.5066", 
    "12.4798", "10.5598"), X342 = c("69.8426", "12.3198", "10.5918"
    ), X343 = c("69.3426", "12.4478", "11.6798"), X344 = c("69.5506", 
    "12.3198", "10.4638"), X345 = c("70.6106", "12.6077", "11.4878"
    ), X346 = c("70.2346", "12.5757", "9.9198"), X347 = c("71.5106", 
    "12.9277", "10.8798"), X348 = c("71.4706", "13.1197", "10.8478"
    ), X349 = c("71.8026", "12.9277", "10.4958"), X350 = c("72.3826", 
    "12.5437", "10.4318"), X351 = c("71.4106", "12.9597", "11.1678"
    ), X352 = c("71.6746", "12.8317", "10.4638"), X353 = c("72.9185", 
    "12.8317", "10.8478"), X354 = c("71.1786", "14.0797", "10.7838"
    ), X355 = c("71.1066", "13.9517", "10.5278"), X356 = c("69.5986", 
    "12.2878", "10.2078"), X357 = c("70.1186", "12.5437", "10.4958"
    ), X358 = c("71.2186", "13.2477", "10.2718"), X359 = c("70.7306", 
    "12.7357", "10.8158"), X360 = c("69.9226", "13.7597", "10.3998"
    ), X361 = c("69.2346", "13.0877", "10.8798"), X362 = c("71.4666", 
    "13.9197", "10.3038"), X363 = c("70.4466", "12.6397", "9.56781"
    ), X364 = c("70.7466", "12.5437", "10.8798"), X365 = c("71.0586", 
    "13.7917", "10.9118"), X366 = c("70.7946", "13.7917", "10.4638"
    ), X367 = c("71.4546", "13.0877", "11.2958"), X368 = c("72.0826", 
    "14.0477", "11.3278"), X369 = c("72.2946", "12.8957", "10.8798"
    ), X370 = c("72.5306", "13.8557", "10.2718"), X371 = c("72.7465", 
    "13.0237", "11.9678"), X372 = c("74.7305", "13.9837", "10.9118"
    ), X373 = c("73.3705", "13.1197", "9.8878"), X374 = c("73.6345", 
    "12.2878", "10.8798"), X375 = c("74.3105", "13.3437", "11.1678"
    ), X376 = c("74.3545", "12.7037", "11.0078"), X377 = c("74.6865", 
    "11.9358", "10.9118"), X378 = c("74.2625", "13.3117", "10.4318"
    ), X379 = c("73.4585", "13.5997", "10.3358"), X380 = c("75.9545", 
    "12.8957", "10.6878"), X381 = c("74.2065", "12.6077", "10.5278"
    ), X382 = c("73.4785", "11.4878", "10.0158"), X383 = c("72.4066", 
    "12.2558", "10.1118"), X384 = c("72.9025", "12.6077", "11.2638"
    ), X385 = c("73.4505", "12.6717", "10.5598"), X386 = c("72.6425", 
    "12.9597", "10.1758"), X387 = c("72.4026", "11.9998", "9.8558"
    ), X388 = c("73.0025", "12.3198", "10.2398"), X389 = c("72.3866", 
    "12.4158", "10.0798"), X390 = c("65.4147", "10.5278", "8.38383"
    ), X391 = c("55.4749", "9.37581", "7.67985"), X392 = c("54.0749", 
    "9.31181", "7.58385"), X393 = c("52.9269", "9.47181", "7.00786"
    ), X394 = c("53.3669", "10.1438", "8.35183"), X395 = c("55.5429", 
    "9.7598", "7.55185"), X396 = c("56.4589", "10.1438", "7.23186"
    ), X397 = c("57.4109", "10.2718", "8.25583"), X398 = c("58.7708", 
    "11.0718", "7.99984"), X399 = c("60.4588", "10.7198", "8.60783"
    ), X400 = c("63.1027", "10.5278", "9.27981"), X401 = c("64.7667", 
    "11.4238", "10.1118"), X402 = c("61.7748", "9.59981", "8.83182"
    ), X403 = c("60.3028", "10.5598", "8.44783"), X404 = c("62.9307", 
    "10.9758", "10.1118"), X405 = c("64.8587", "11.8078", "9.66381"
    ), X406 = c("66.4707", "11.7758", "11.3598"), X407 = c("67.2467", 
    "12.7037", "11.0398"), X408 = c("69.0506", "13.3757", "9.9838"
    ), X409 = c("69.3546", "12.7677", "10.3038"), X410 = c("70.7386", 
    "13.3437", "10.5598"), X411 = c("72.3306", "13.3117", "11.9998"
    ), X412 = c("72.3586", "14.9437", "11.1358"), X413 = c("72.0746", 
    "14.4317", "11.6478"), X414 = c("71.5946", "14.4317", "12.0638"
    ), X415 = c("70.9106", "13.7597", "11.6158"), X416 = c("68.6306", 
    "12.7677", "11.0078"), X417 = c("67.6026", "13.5037", "11.5198"
    ), X418 = c("67.3787", "12.3838", "11.2318"), X419 = c("66.3187", 
    "12.4798", "11.0078"), X420 = c("65.5987", "13.1517", "10.3998"
    ), X421 = c("64.9427", "13.2477", "9.9838"), X422 = c("64.3667", 
    "12.3838", "10.9438"), X423 = c("63.3507", "12.4478", "10.3038"
    ), X424 = c("61.5668", "12.6077", "10.3358"), X425 = c("59.2788", 
    "12.7357", "10.2718"), X426 = c("58.4828", "12.4478", "10.3678"
    ), X427 = c("56.2229", "11.6158", "10.0798"), X428 = c("56.2349", 
    "11.9358", "9.9198"), X429 = c("54.3309", "11.9678", "10.2398"
    ), X430 = c("50.011", "10.1438", "9.43981"), X431 = c("49.143", 
    "11.2958", "10.1118"), X432 = c("48.107", "9.50381", "8.79982"
    ), X433 = c("46.7871", "9.31181", "8.31983"), X434 = c("49.999", 
    "9.8558", "9.72781"), X435 = c("42.5152", "9.53581", "7.67985"
    ), X436 = c("29.9394", "7.29585", "5.72789"), X437 = c("28.0914", 
    "7.93584", "5.72789"), X438 = c("26.5035", "7.39185", "5.72789"
    ), X439 = c("21.2156", "6.91186", "5.88788"), X440 = c("18.7756", 
    "6.11188", "6.11188"), X441 = c("18.9236", "7.03986", "5.82388"
    ), X442 = c("17.4917", "6.75187", "5.88788"), X443 = c("17.2317", 
    "5.72789", "4.63991"), X444 = c("13.6757", "5.63189", "4.73591"
    ), X445 = c("12.8197", "5.75988", "5.0879"), X446 = c("12.6117", 
    "6.23988", "5.50389"), X447 = c("17.7676", "7.10386", "6.43187"
    ), X448 = c("14.3597", "7.07186", "6.39987"), X449 = c("14.5877", 
    "6.81586", "6.46387")), row.names = 4:6, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem, thank you for the assistance!